# Legend Items in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, legend, atlas

Using the Qgis atlas functions im having trouble with the atlas filtering out the features that do not show up in the map extent.

For example i want the full color ramp to show up, even 
though there are some features that are not within the atlas map extent.

Below is what the atlas is currently doing:[image: Current Legend set up using qgis atlas function]

This is what i need it to look like [image: The full legend showing all the different styles, not just the ones on the map]

Everything is set up and working in the atlas coverage layer to dictate the layers that should be on and off. The legend needs to change with the atlas feature, but not limit the features displayed

I feel like there is some options in the Filter legend by expression options, but im not sure what expression can get me to the result i need.

Comment: There's an option under the Legend Items / properties section to 'Only show items inside current atlas feature' - did you see that?

Comment: Yes, that is what is allowing me to only show things on the legend that are within my atlas feature... And it does very well. It does it too well and literally only shows those features, and is filtering out some layer symbology. I want to show only the layers in my atlas feature, but also show the full symbology, not just the symbology matching the features displayed in the map frame

Comment: Maybe if you added a 2nd legend - one for everything, and one just for atlas features?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Query Builder to filter some feature from your polygon layer. If this is the case, then you cannot show the full legend in your atlas map because you already filtered out all the features using Query Builder. Alternatively, clear the filter from Building Query, and symbolize your polygon using `Categorized` or `Rule-based` symbology, then uncheck those polygon styles that you don't want to show and filter them using `Filter with` option located inside the Atlas configuration.

Example:

I have this polygon grid

[image]

I unchecked two styled polygons (Purple and dark yellow colors):

[image]

Use `Filter with` to filter those hidden polygons. This will make `Preview Atlas` to skip those hidden polygons:

[image]

Uncheck the option `Only show items inside current atlas feature`. As you can see the purple color is not displayed although it is located under the green color and at the same you will see the full legend inside your map, not only those located within the atlas.

[image]

Comment: Im not using the query builder to filter out certain features. The symbology features not in the legend are also not in the data layer. But i still want to show all the symbology features in the legend (the full color ramp). Im also not sure how to change the legend with the next atlas feature, (symbolize a new layer for the next map) with the "only show items inside current atlas feature" unchecked.

Comment: @MatthewJSlezak If the features you want to symbolize are not in the data layer, it is impossible to show full color symbology. The only solution to your case is to create a graphic legend (draw the polygons by hand) using polygon tools located in the `Layout Manager toolbar`